# if statement in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I form that edits a table in the database. However a user may not selcect an image so if they dont I do not want to update that field. I have tried a couple of ways to do this but none work. Is there an easy way? Thanks.

```
if ($_POST["image"]!=='') { 
      $image= "image=%s"; 
      $imageValue =    "GetSQLValueString(".$_POST['image'].", 'text'),";
};

$insertSQL = sprintf("UPDATE taxi SET name=%s, taxi_link=%s, ". $image." WHERE id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['link'], "text"),
                   $imageValue,
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));
```

Comment: Your above attempt doesn't work for one reason. The `,` after `taxi_link=%s`. Remove that `,` and change 2nd row to `$image= ", image=%s";`.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, there is still one issue with that in that $imageValue is blank but still puts a blank entry giving an error

Comment: I fixed your query in below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a framework like CodeIgniter you can simply:

```
$arr_values = array('name' => $_POST['name'],
                    'taxi_link' => $_POST['link']);

if ( ! $_POST["image"])
    $arr_values['image'] = $_POST['image'];

$this->db->update($arr_values, array('id' => $_POST['id']));
```

The update() simply handles an array, and you can simply add additional values to that array based on conditions.

Personally, I made my own function like this one which works perfect with adding and using array values.

Fixed your query:

```
$image = '';
if ($_POST["image"] !== '')
      $image= ", image=".GetSQLValueString($_POST['image'], 'text');

$insertSQL = sprintf("UPDATE taxi SET name=%s, taxi_link=%s {$image} WHERE id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['link'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));
```

Comment: sorry not an option here though

Comment: Check comment on your answer. It says what's wrong with your example.

Comment: thanks again for the help, it works if I leave the image field blank but when I select an image I get the error Too few arguments in taxi-edit.php on line 49
Query was empty

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you properly, couldn't you put the whole thing in the if statement?

```
if ($_POST["image"]!=='') { 
      $image= "image=%s"; 
      $imageValue =    "GetSQLValueString(".$_POST['image'].", 'text'),";
      $insertSQL = sprintf("UPDATE taxi SET name=%s, taxi_link=%s, ". $image." WHERE id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['link'], "text"),
                   $imageValue,
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));
      //execute query
} else {
    //tell the user nothing happened
} //no semicolon required
```

So now it will **only** build and execute the query if the image is specified, and you can do something else if it's not specified

Comment: I though this was what he meant first, but he means is there any more elegant (and functional) way to update the image column then he already does.

Comment: yeah thought of this but was wondering was there a way without writing multiple queriies